# C++ Move Assignment Operator Return Type

Tags: c++

What is the correct return type for a move assignment operator?

```
const type&
```

or

```
type&
```

?

And why? (I do not think I fully understand how the compiler determines between l/r/x values.)

For example, consider an implementation of a vector class.

A function may return a vector.

```
vector myfunc()
{
    vector v;
    // add content to v
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    vector v2;
    v2 = myfunc;
}
```

We want `myfunc` to return [?] an expiring value [?], ie; we want the move assignment operator to be called, not the copy assignment operator.

A copy assignment operator may look like this:

```
const Vector& operator=(const Vector& vector)
{
    if(this != &vector)
    {
        if(m_capacity_x != vector.m_capacity_x)
        {
            delete [] m_data;
            m_data = new T[vector.m_capacity_x];
        }

        m_size = vector.m_size_x;
        m_capacity_x = vector.m_capacity_x;

        std::copy(&(vector.m_data[0]), &(vector.m_data[vector.m_size_x - 1]), m_data);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Whereas a move assignment operator may look like this:

```
Vector& operator=(Vector&& vector)
{
    m_data = vector.m_data;
    m_size = vector.m_size;
    m_capacity = vector.m_capacity;
    m_data = nullptr;
    m_size = 0;
    m_capacity = 0;

    return *this;
}
```

But is the return type correct? Should it be `Vector&&` [does this exist?] or `const Vector&`?

Comment: Both your "assignment" operators actually format the hard drive. Please return *something*.

Comment: @Fanael err, format the hard drive?

Comment: The behavior when reaching the end of a function returning non-`void` without returning a value is undefined.

Comment: What's the relevance of the comment about hard drives?

Comment: It's one of the infinitely many possible results of undefined behavior. Coincidentally, it's the one favored by Hell++.

Comment: Guys, I'm still new here. I notice this question is at -3. Why?

Comment: @flatmouse I'm not new here, but my questions often get lots of downvotes because I make mistakes in my code. They usually get upvoted at later dates after corrections have been made. It seems to be the "de-facto" method people here use to say "correct something in your question". This community is not tolerant to people who make mistakes.

Comment: @flatmouse: Questions usually get downvoted because they don't help Stackoverflow. Although I don't understand what's so horrible about this particular question here. I don't think it's particularly great, but I'd not downvote it either. Questions are upvoted if they help Stackoverflow, i.e. if they add interesting content to the site or will likely help future readers because they are written such that a reasonable Google search for the same problem will find them.

Answer (score 3):

We can ask, what's the point of assigning to an rvalue? Assignments are normally done on lvalues, so that's what you should return. Also, if your value was initially const, why would it support assignment? Otherwise, if it's not const, why force it?

Therefore, the normal course of things is that assignment operators always return a non-const lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the return type of an assignment operator is `Vector&`, but `const Vector&` is acceptable if you don't want people making funky assignment chains `(((v1 = v2) = v3) = v4)`. Move assignment and copy assignment are both "assignment". It would be unexpected for one assignment operator to have a different return type than the other, so whichever one you pick, you should stick with.

It would be VERY weird to return `Vector&&`. Just because you used the move assignment operator does not mean your object is magically an rvalue. You'd have to specifically cast it, and then it would be possible to accidentally move back out of that instance.

```
void some_function(Vector);
Vector get_some_Vector();

Vector f;
some_function(f = get_some_Vector()); //oops f is empty now
```

Comment: @user3728501 I changed the example a little, but basically what this does is call a function to get a new `Vector` and assign it to `f`, then call a function that operates on `f`'s new value. If you return `Vector&&` from the move assignment, at the end of the function call, `f` is probably empty.

Comment: I still don't understand. How is `Vector&&` to be interpreted here?

Comment: @user3728501 Returning `Vector&&` means your object will be interpreted as an xvalue, and not the lvalue is probably is. Compare [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02dd73f100c76fea) to [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b92eeab7d4ea130). I just changed the return type of the move assignment operator.

Comment: From that it looks like `Vector&&` makes the code call the wrong operator anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally familiar with "move assignment operators". I work with some older compilers that don't support c++11, but the documentation suggests that the operator should just return `type&`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx

I just did a search for c++ move assignment.

Also, in your examples, you didn't return anything from the operators. You should return something unless the return type is void.